# Why are right sides of boxes not showing in IE7+8

Tags: internet-explorer, css

Of course when developing IE is causing me headaches.
This page with rounded corner shaded divs looks good in all browsers: http://www.toptrouwen.nl

But the same sort of divs on this page http://www.toptrouwen.nl/trouwlocaties/zoeken/?search=1 look good in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but messed up in IE7, IE8 and IE9.

Why?

Comment: Try posting your HTML/CSS here so we don't have to dig through your code for you, and for the benefit of future visitors if your question is answered.

Comment: @65Fbef05: thanks for noticing. It's rendered by an ASP.NET gridview. When adding attribute cellspacing="1" all is good again :)
Thanks!

Comment: Cool, I changed my response to an answer, since it wound up solving your problem. :)

Comment: Good, I was wondering already how I could reward you for your response :)
Done and done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that IE is rendering your table differently than the other browsers. In the first link, your divs aren't inside of a table, which is the case in your second link. Get rid of or modify the table and I'll bet the inconsistency between your two pages goes away too.

Answer (score 1):

The rounded corner for what seems to be a search modal look good on all browsers for me, since the rounded corner is an image and it's not done by CSS.

as far as the shaded background, it's using Box Shadow which is not supported by IE8 and lower. to see a list of what css properties are supported by which browers look at the link below:

http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus